# Should the OIDs be in the same order as that MIB tree when SNMP trap is sent?

Tags: snmp, mib, oid, snmp-trap

Assume I have MIB tree like -

```
---ABC
 |
 ---EFG
  |
  ---HIJ
   |
   |--mno
   |
   |--pqr
   |
   |--tuv
   |
   |--xyz
```

In this MIB tree, we see OIDs `mno, pqr, tuv, xyz` are to under `HIJ`.

When I send a SNMP trap, I need to send information related to OIDs - `mno, pqr, tuv and xyz`.
Is there a rule that I should be sending the OIDs in the same order as seen in the MIB tree? i.e., `mno, prq, tuv, xyz`? Or can we send the OIDs in any order like `tuv, xyz, prq and mno`?

Since we just dont send the value of OIDs alone, it should be okay i believe. Since the value would be sent along with the OID number. Please confirm this.

Comment: In SNMP v2 TRAP PDU, the only requirements are the first variable binding must be  the time, while the second must be the enterprise ID. All remaining ones can be served in any order you like (though it is recommended that you follow your TRAP definition in the MIB document).

Comment: @Lex Li: I didn't get what's the 'time' and 'enterprise ID' variable bindings?

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/search/rfc3416#page-22

Comment: Okay. Got it. Thanks

Comment: @DarshanL So, did you get your answer?

Answer (score 1):

No, the order does not have to match the numerical ordering of the OIDs.

However, if your notification mentions objects in its `OBJECTS` list, then all those objects must be bound to the notification, and they must be bound in the order they were listed under `OBJECTS`.

> [**4.2.6.  The SNMPv2-Trap-PDU**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3416#page-21)
>
> *[..]* If the OBJECTS clause is present in the invocation of
> the corresponding NOTIFICATION-TYPE macro, then each corresponding
> variable, as instantiated by this notification, is copied, in order,
> to the variable-bindings field.  If any additional variables are
> being included (at the option of the generating SNMP entity), then
> each is copied to the variable-bindings field.

That's not for a *logically* technical reason: as you point out, the values are accompanied by an OID, so the manager will always know what object is being sent (indeed, many managers silently permit out-of-order bindings). I assume the rule exists to make things easier for implementations, particularly older ones or those on resource-constrained systems.

Anyway, after binding the objects named in the `OBJECTS` list, you can bind any additional objects you like, and those may be bound in any order.